# Isolate duplicate objects in a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, duplicates, grouping

Given a list of objects with possible duplicates, I can find plenty of examples of how to get a `List<IGrouping<'a, MyObject>>` or how to *remove* duplicates. But what I want to do is just isolate the duplicates in a list of their own, based on a group, and while ignoring the original.

So let's say I have this list:

```
Prop1     Prop2     Prop3
---------------------------
foo1      bar1      doesntMatter1
foo2      bar2      doesntMatter2
foo2      bar2      doesntMatter21 // first duplicate
foo2      bar2      doesntMatter22 // second duplicate 
foo3      bar2      doesntMatter32
```

The rule is, the combo of Prop1 and Prop2 can't be duplicated. But Prod3 doesn't matter. So what I would like is a list that looks like this:

```
Prop1     Prop2     Prop3
---------------------------
foo2      bar2      doesntMatter21
foo2      bar2      doesntMatter22
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

And...

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = new();
myObjects.Add(new() { Prop1 = "foo1", Prop2 = "bar1", Prop3 = "doesntMatter1" });
myObjects.Add(new() { Prop1 = "foo2", Prop2 = "bar2", Prop3 = "doesntMatter2" });
myObjects.Add(new() { Prop1 = "foo2", Prop2 = "bar2", Prop3 = "doesntMatter21" });
myObjects.Add(new() { Prop1 = "foo2", Prop2 = "bar2", Prop3 = "doesntMatter22" });
myObjects.Add(new() { Prop1 = "foo3", Prop2 = "bar3", Prop3 = "doesntMatter3" });

var dupes = (myObjects.GroupBy(m => new { m.Prop1, m.Prop2 }).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)).ToList();

foreach (var item in dupes)
{
    // How do I get my isolated list of duplicates?
}
```

`dupes` ends up being that `List<IGrouping<'a, MyObject>>`. But I can't figure out how to go from that to my isolated list of duplicates.

Comment: You would enumerate `item` to get the `MyObject` instances that were grouped together (by `item.Key`, which of the anonymous type used in `GroupBy`).

Answer (score 1):

Ok found it:

```
var isolatedList = dupes.SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

Edited per Lance's comment below.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `dupes.SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1))`?  That will flatten the result of taking the last `Count() - 1` items (the "duplicates") in each grouping.  This, instead, will flatten the result of taking all `Count()` items (the "original" + the "duplicates") in each grouping and then omit only the first item (the "original") from the first group.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews, I tested both and they both gave me the same results. But I will make the data more complex and test again.

Comment: Ok, yes! You are correct! Good catch.